# codeigniter on xampp wants me to use index.php in uri

Tags: codeigniter, url, xampp, uri

I have a problem with setting up a local testing environment using codeigniter and an already existing code.

Well, the problem is, that I can't open a page, without having "index.php" in my URL. So, "test.mydomain.local/index.php/search" works fine while "test.mydomain.local/search" does not. But all links in the code, excluding the action-URLs in form-tags, doesn't have this "index.php" in the URL.

How can I solve the problem, that codeigniter or the xampp need this "index.php" in the URL? Do I need to change something in my code or maybe in .htaccess?

Here is my config.php

```html
$config['base_url'] = "http://test.mydomain.local/";
$config['index_page'] = "index.php";
$config['uri_protocol'] = "AUTO";
```

Well, this code forces the "index.php" in the action-URL in form tags. But actually I dont want to have this index.php in any URL. So that my config.php should look like this, I guess:

```html
$config['base_url'] = "http://test.mydomain.local/";
$config['index_page'] = "";
$config['uri_protocol'] = "AUTO";
```

Here is the .htaccess

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    ### force www
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) h t t p : / / w w w . m y d o m a i n . c o m/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.local [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) h t t p : / / t e s t . d o m a i n . l o c a l/$1 [R=301,L]

    ### if the is not a request for an existing file or directory
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    ### and the URI does not end with a /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^([^?]*)/($|\?)

    ### redirect and add the slash.
    RewriteRule ^([^?]*) $1/ [L,R=301]

    ### if the is not a request for an existing file or directory
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    # rewrite to index.php passing the URI as a path, QSA will preserve the existing query string
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
    </IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
        # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
        # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
        # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

        ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
    </IfModule>
```

Can anybody help me? It is driving me nuts!

Comment: there are lots of questions and answer like this problem.You can look the documentation https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

Answer (score 0):

I use xampp and have found this htaccess is best. Do not for get to put your base url in  config/config.php and remove index.

.htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Your config.php

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Base Site URL
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| URL to your CodeIgniter root. Typically this will be your base URL,
| WITH a trailing slash:
|
|   http://example.com/
|
| If this is not set then CodeIgniter will try guess the protocol, domain
| and path to your installation. However, you should always configure this
| explicitly and never rely on auto-guessing, especially in production
| environments.
|
*/

$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project name/';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Index File
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Typically this will be your index.php file, unless you've renamed it to
| something else. If you are using mod_rewrite to remove the page set this
| variable so that it is blank.
|
*/
$config['index_page'] = '';
```